# How do you skip over a specified value within an array?

Tags: arrays, c

I am attempting to make a GPA average calculator where the user can input up to 30 GPA scores. The user has the option to continue adding GPA scores if < 30 or calculate the current GPA average with the given scores. I am trying to make my code work so that it will skip over elements within the array that contain the value 0 (inputted by the user), this way they will not be included in the sum total. I tried different if statements in order to skip over values that contained 0 but all have been unsuccessful.

Input: 10, 2, 38
Output: 16.00 (GPA average)

Input: 10, 2, 0, 38
Output: 12.00 (GPA average)
Desired Output: 16.00 <-- I want to skip over any "0" values entered by the user.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

int option = 0;
int iArray[30] = { 0 };
int choice;
int counter = 0;
int sum = 0;
float average;

  do {
        printf("\nEnter GPA score here: ");
        scanf(" %d", &iArray[counter]);
        counter++;

        printf("\n1\tEnter a new GPA? Please enter \"1\".");
        printf("\n2\tCalculate the current GPA average? Please enter \"2\".\n");
        printf("\n\nPlease enter choice here: ");
        scanf(" %d", &choice);
    
  } while (choice == 1 && counter < 30);

  if (choice == 2) {
    for (int x = 0; x < counter; x++) {
        if (iArray[x] >= 1) {   //skip over elements with value of 0
            sum += iArray[x];
          }
      }
  }

  average = sum / counter;

  printf("\n\nThe average GPA is %.2f ", average);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `counter <= 30` should be `counter < 30`. Right now you have the potential to write to the 30th index of `iArray`, invoking [Undefined Behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) (valid indices are 0 to 29).

Comment: if `iArray[x]` is zero, then `sum += iArray[x]` doesn't do anything anyway. The problem is the counter gets increasing when the user inputs zero. Roll back the counter if a zero is entered, and you are good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not adding GPAs less than `1` to your `sum`, but then your average is simply dividing by the `counter` variable which you had counting *all* of the grades input.

If you introduce a new counter variable keep track of how many zero GPAs there are, you can subtract this from the overall count of grades input.

Please note that if you are dividing an `int` sum by an `int` counter, you will get an `int`, even if you are assigning that value to a `float` variable. To avoid this, cast your `sum` to `float` so that floating point math takes place.

Comment: Better yet to do a `counter--` in order to disregard inputs of `0`.

Comment: That is a solution. I'm always a little partial to not throwing away data that _might_ be needed later.

Answer (score 2):

Its a logical issue here. Even though `sum` is done when values are more than 0, `counter` is total number of inputs.

You can maintain another counter e.g. `counter_filtered` and increment it only when `if` condition is passed.

```
  int counter_filtered = 0      //--> New variable
  if (choice == 2) {
    for (int x = 0; x < counter; x++) {
        if (iArray[x] >= 1) {   //skip over elements with value of 0
            sum += iArray[x];
            counter_filtered++;      //--> New variable increment
          }
      }
  }

  average = sum / counter_filtered; //--> New variable usage in calculations
```